# como imprimir en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicacion sencilla en VB6 la cual imprime texto simple en una impresora de red mi codigo es el sigueinte:

```
Open "\\PC1\impresora1" For Output As #2
  Print #1, "Hola Mundo"
Close #2
```

Ahora estoy tratando de utilizar windows form c# para poder hacer lo mismo pero no encuentro el codigo equivalente que podria realizar dicha tarea. Alguien con mas experiencia en C# me puede orientar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar directo a impresion texto en .net deberias usar la clase `PrintDocument`

[PrintDocument Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.5)

entonces si haces algo como esto

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string textoImprimir = "Hola Mundo";

        PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
        p.PrintPage += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(textoImprimir, 
                                     new Font("Times New Roman", 12), 
                                     new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
                                     new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, 
                                                     p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
        };

        p.Print();

    }
}
```

Puedes indicar la impresora asignando su nombre mediente la configuracion

[PrinterSettings.PrinterName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername?view=netframework-4.8)

---

Tambien se podria evaluar usar las `api de windows`, pero es algo mas complejo

[Printing Directly to the Printer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/printing-directly-to-the-printer/)

veras que se usa el `[DllImport()]` para declarar las apis que permiten abrir la impresora